# Dependence of point cloud data on camera parameters?

Tags: 3d, photogrammetry

I want to do a 3d-reconstruction of a road surface using 'Structure from motion'. After taking the required image set of the road surface, I want to obtain the point cloud data using some open source applications (e.g. http://ccwu.me/vsfm/). Now , the question is regarding the spacing of the point cloud data that I will obtain after going through all the necessary steps i.e. :

How will the spacing between the data points depend upon my camera parameters? For example, is there a way to compare the spacing of the data points qualitatively or quantitatively if the image set is taken from say, a 15 MP camera and a 20 MP camera ?

i.e. I want to know comparatively how fine are my details of the road surface being captured from a , using the same example, if the image set is taken from a 15 MP camera and a 20 MP camera ?

Note : The data is of the form (x,y,z), where (x,y) refers to the location of the road surface and 'z' refers to the elevation of the road surface at that (x,y). Here , by spacing , I refer to the space between the location of the reconstructed road surface i.e. space between the (x,y) points .

Say, by using a 15 MP camera I got my data points, they have an average spacing of 2mm. Can I make a judgement beforehand that what will be my average spacing if I use a 20 MP camera and follow the same steps in the road surface reconstruction ? Can I estimate that it will be 1.5 mm (for example) ?

Comment: As a relatively new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't assume that. First of all (and correct me if I misunderstood) you are assuming that 3D points are spaced equally throughout your Point Cloud? That is actually a bad assumption since software such as  http://ccwu.me/vsfm/ outputs a **sparse** structure from motion (SFM) point cloud. Are you considering the complete pipeline where a **dense** point cloud is computed?

Either way, projected points from SFM come from what we call in Computer Vision, **feature points**. Feature points are small patches detected in photographs that help the triangulation process from the 2D space to 3D (i.e. two similar patches may indeed belong to the same 3D position).

Image features are indeed dependent from the quality of input images, thus, higher quality images should offer refined features. It will in some cases increase the output number of 3D points in the point cloud. However, you can not predict how newer projected point will be distributed in 3D.

Hope it helps, will be sure to update this answer if needed whenever I am free from work.

Comment: I am not assuming that the point cloud is equally spaced. i know that it is scattered. And yes I am considering the complete pipeline where we obtain the dense point cloud. Thank you for answering !